# is asus 15 x509ja-bq835t ram upgradable?

Tags: memory, upgrade, asus-laptop, asus

I purchased asus 15 x509ja bq835t. I tried to search if it has empty memory slots and upgradable. But I couldn't find any sure information. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Does it have empty memory slots?

> **ASUS Laptop 15 X509JA**
>
> Memory
>
> 4 GB Onboard memory, 1 x SO-DIMM socket , total up to 8 GB SDRAM

Source [ASUS Laptop 15 X509JA Specifications](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-Laptop-15-X509JA/specifications/)

Comment: But they also say specifications are subject to change without any notice and may differ by country

Comment: @tenzing As per DavidPostill it is almost certainly upgradable.  I expect the changes they are talking about are configuration options, rather then physical slots - to do otherwise would cause to much confusion which is easily eliminated with a new model number If you won't accept answers from people who have not seen your laptop this is not the place.

Comment: Thanks..........